# Why does "sbt new" create a directory named "target" in current directory instead of project home?

Tags: scala, sbt

New to SBT.

Why does 'sbt new' create directory named 'target' under current directory? It appears like 'sbt new' is polluting the parent directory of project home.

```sh
 my-projects-dir> sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

Above command created a directory named 'target' under 'my-projects-dir'. Project home (play-scala-seed) got created sucessfully (and even compiles successfully).

The behavior is the same for any new project and not specifically for the mentioned project.

Comment: This problem has been solved in sbt 1.2.1 (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4339). Which version are you using?

Comment: Problem is solved only in 1.2.1. Issue is observed even in sbt version 1.3.1. Posted https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4339#issuecomment-542027420

Comment: I can reproduce it. I recommend you to open an issue on sbt/sbt (with the link to the old fix) and close this question (because there's no answer to it, it's just a regression that needs a fix).

Comment: Reported a defect on sbt/sbt - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5190 for version 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to sbt 1.9. This is no longer an issue. It was reported back with sbt version 1.0.

This PR by a sbt contributor fixes the behavior https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/4033